# looping through directories in bash skipping a particular directory name

Tags: linux, bash, for

I am trying to loop through directories within a given folder and I want to skip a particular directory name. I have written this bash script to do it, but this is giving me errors. Please tell me where I am going wrong:

```
for f in *
do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        if [ -d "TEST"];then
        echo "skip TEST directory"
        continue
        fi
    echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

I want to skip TEST directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is incorrect. Try changing your 2nd if statement to the following.

```bash
for f in *
do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then # Modify to [[ ! -L "$f" && -d "$f" ]] to check only for directories and not symlinks since -d will also get symlinks
        if [ "$f" = "TEST" ]; then
            echo "Skipping $f dir"
            continue
        fi
        # Code ...
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note `=` as the standard equivalent to `==` and `!` as the standard equivalent to `-not`. See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697). That -regex is functionally equivalent to `-regex '.*/TEST.*'` or its `-path '*/TEST*` standard equivalent. Maybe you meant `find . -name TEST -prune -o type d -print`. Also remember [`echo` can't be used for arbitrary data](/q/65803).

Comment: Note that `[ -d "$f" ]` also returns true on symlinks to directories while `find`'s `-type d`  excludes them.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes I was looking for something like prune lol. I had no clue it was bad to loop with find, I always viewed it as being more powerful with more options specifically with `-exec` I will modify it to use exec for commands. I was just trying to provide alternatives if they were just doing something simple that a single find command could do. I will add checks for symlinks too.